# Prove that the continuous function is ≠ ∅

Tags: functions

$f$ is a continuous function at $I$ , $I \subset R$ , $f(I) \subset I$:

prove that:

$\{x \in I : f(x)=x\} \neq \emptyset  \iff  \{x ∈ I : f \circ f(x)=x \} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: I assume that I should be an interval for your hypotesis to work.

Comment: Is the interval closed (for closed intervals the result is trivial) or open?

Comment: i don't know , is there going to be any difference if open or closed ?

Comment: Yes. All continuous functions $[a,b]\to [a,b]$ have a fixed point.

Comment: ok , can u give me the resultt of both of them ? :p

Comment: @Momo Yeah I is an interval

Comment: If $f(x)$ does not have a fixed point, then either for all $x\in I$ it holds $f(x)> x$ or for all $x\in I$ it holds $f(x)<x$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli , so have u got any idea how can i prove that equivalence ?

Comment: Yes, the one I've just written.

Comment: i didn't understand it well

Comment: can u explain more please ?

Comment: I wrote it in more detail in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$

If there is an $x$ with $f(x)=x$ by applying $f$ one more time we get $f\circ f(x)=f(x)=x$, so x is a fixed point of $f\circ f$

$\Leftarrow$

Suppose $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in I$. We have either $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in I$ or $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in I$. (Otherwise we can apply the intermediate value theorem and prove that $f$ has a fixed point, contradiction)

For $f(x)<x$ we apply $f$ on both sides one more time and we get $f\circ f(x)<f(x)<x$ for all $x\in I$. Thus $f\circ f$ does not have a fixed point.

For $f(x)>x$ the argument is similar.